# NetSuite Saves Search Formula (Field Contains)

Tags: netsuite

I am new to writing formulas in NetSuite saved searches. I need to write a formula that says "If {field} contains 'XYZ' then '123'." There are too many different instances to do a case when for each instance. Please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN {entity} = 'XYZ' THEN '123' END